# How to http request data first and then call Polymer()?

Tags: polymer

Very often I noticed this pattern in a data component (in the Polymer shop and news demo app):

```
<script>
    (function() {

        var categoryList = [
            {name: 'top_stories', title: 'Top Stories'},
            {name: 'doodles', title: 'Doodles'},
            {name: 'chrome', title: 'Chrome'},
            {name: 'search', title: 'Search'},
            {name: 'shopping_payments', title: 'Shopping & Payments'},
            {name: 'nonprofits', title: 'Nonprofits'}
        ];

        var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');

        Polymer();

    })();

</script>
```

Is it possible to make an http request firstly to get the `categoryList` from the remote server and then call Polymer?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just calling `Polymer();` won't do anything useful, since you don't provide any data to the `Polymer` function nor do you save the result of the call. You can always obtain data in a non-Polymer way and then assign it to an instance of a custom element via property binding. It's a bit complicated since you need to be careful that the custom element is instantiated when the HTTP request finishes. If you don't have any particular reasons, it would advise you to use `iron-ajax` and go with Polymer all the way.

Comment: If you want to use `iron-ajax`, check this out: http://plnkr.co/edit/z1BDtC?p=info.